# Validating numeric input with type of reason code selected from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php form for inventory adjustments to collect the unit change (+/-) in a text field and a reason code from a dropdown field.  I need to verify that a positive unit change gets a reason code that is positive (select value >= 20) and a negative change gets a reason code < 20.  Ideally, I would like to hide the submit button until the fields indicate both positive or negative.

I have seen examples of fields matching, but I am thinking this will be more of an if, elseif condtion

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<!--
//--------------------------------
// This code checks to make sure the adjustment value matches
// the reason for the adjustment.
//--------------------------------
function checkAdj() 
{
    var qtyCheck = document.getElementbyId("invChg");
    var codeCheck = document.getElementbyId("reason");


        if (qtyCheck.value > 0 && codeCheck.value < 20 )
{
    alert('You are increasing inventory, but using a decreasing reason!');
    $("#chgSubmit").hide();
} else if (qtyCheck.value < 0 && codeCheck.value > 20 )
{
    alert('You are decreasing inventory, but using a increasing reason!');
    $("#chgSubmit").hide();
} else {
    $("#chgSubmit").show();
}

}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: What's the question though? Is it not working? I can see you're expecting text values to be numbers without converting them, which might cause you an issue. If you post a full test with html we can help more.

Comment: Thanks, I will review and set up a test site

Answer (score 0):

just use the [constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation) and the proper input type?

disabling/hiding the the submit button *can* be a bad UX chosig for not knowing what mig be wrong with the form or thinking: "Ah, it dose not have a submit button, it must be auto saving things".

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9788/disabled-submit-button-on-form-vs-allow-submit-then-show-errors

just simple web component might be all.

```css
:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" required min="0" max="20">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

look how i don't have to give any hints as to what's wrong with the form if you try to submit it.

fyi, doing `const qtyCheck = input.valueAsNumber` would give you an actual number and not a string

Comment: You make a very good point.  The issue is the user enters a numeric value for the change in the count (which can be either positive or negative) and then needs to provide a reason from a dropdown list containing both positive and negative reasons.  For example the user could make a mistake and type a positive number like 10 when they actually meant to subtract (-10).  I was using the reason code to "validate" the numeric entry.  So if they enter plus ten and then chose the reason "damaged", the alert could ask them is that what they wanted to enter.  I am not comparing the two fields